# Why do Material UI tabs stop working when I use a .map to populate the content dynamically instead of hard coding?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, state, array.prototype.map

I have implemented Material UI's tabs successfully by hard-coding the content, but when I tried to make a  my hard coded tabs with a .map function to populate the content from a data source (simple json), it no longer works. Can anyone see why? The only change I made was to the MyTabs component below where there are now two .map functions instead of hard coded tabs.

Many thanks for your help!

Here is my data:

```
export const TabsData = [
  {
    tabTitle: 'Tab 1',
    tabContent: 'Hello 1',
  },
  {
    tabTitle: 'Tab 2',
    tabContent: 'Hello 2',
  },
  {
    tabTitle: 'Tab 3',
    tabContent: 'Hello 3',
  },
];
```

Here is my MyTabs component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// Material UI
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';

// Data
import { TabsData } from '../../page-templates/full-page-with-tabs/FullPageWithTabsData';

//Components
import TabContentPanel from '../tabs/tab-content-panel/TabContentPanel';

const MyTabs = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const initialTabIndex = 0;
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialTabIndex);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };
  return (
    <>
     <Tabs
       value={value}
       onChange={handleChange}
       aria-label=""
       className={classes.tabHeight}
       classes={{ indicator: classes.indicator }}
     >
      {TabsData.map((tabInfo, index) => (
        <>
         <Tab
            label={tabInfo.tabTitle}
            id={`simple-tab-${index}`}
            ariaControls={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
         />
        </>
       ))}
    </Tabs>
    {TabsData.map((tabInfo, index) => (
        <TabContentPanel value={value} index={index}>
           {tabInfo.tabContent}
        </TabContentPanel>
    ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default MyTabs;
```

And here is the TabsPanel component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// Material UI
import { Box } from '@material-ui/core';

function TabContentPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && <Box className={classes.contentContainer}>{children}</Box>}
    </div>
  );
}

TabContentPanel.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  index: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
};

export default TabContentPanel;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't work because you added some extra `Fragment`s (`<>` and `</>`) in the `Tabs` component and the `Tabs` component doesn't accept a `Fragment` as a child:

If you remove those, it will work as expected:

```
{TabsData.map((tabInfo, index) => (
  <Tab
    label={tabInfo.tabTitle}
    id={`simple-tab-${index}`}
    key={tabInfo.tabTitle}
    ariaControls={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
  />
))}
```

And please use the `key` prop with a unique id if you create an array of elements. [Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Comment: Wohoo! This is working perfectly now! Thank you so much for your help and for the additional advice to include a key. Very much appreciated and has saved me wasting loads of time messing about trying to figure it out! :)

Comment: I used <Tab></Tab>, and it says "tab failed prop type: the prop `children` is not supported. please remove it.", then i changed it to <Tab/>, it worked, what happened?

Comment: Not sure if I can understand your question. You should use the self-closing syntax for tags that don't have any children.